# CSS in Rails Asset Path not processed by ERB in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails app with the following in `/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.erb`:

```
...
#nestedbg {
    background-position: left top;
    background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'siteheader2.png' %>);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
...
```

When I run `rake assets:precompile` and then run `rails s -e production`, everything works as expected.  However, when I remove the precompiled assets and run `rails s` in development, the CSS file comes up as shown above instead of being properly substituted.

I tried putting `config.assets.compile = true` in `/config/environments/development.rb` and that did not help.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Rails 3.1.1 and when I switched the app to use Rails 3.1.3, the problem went away.  I switched back to 3.1.1 to see if the issue came back and it did not.

I'm guessing that it was a problem with one of the gems and the update to 3.1.3 brought other gem updates with it.

Answer (score 8):

I honestly cannot say why this is not interpreted correctly in your case, but I have a much better workaround to offer: skip erb interpreting altogether.

You can do this like so:

```
/* styles.css.scss */
background-image:url(image_path("siteheader2.png"));
```

If you did not have a chance to I would also suggest to [have a look at SASS](http://sass-lang.com/): it is integrated in the Rails asset pipeline and lets you do cool things like variable declarations, nesting, mixins, ...

Comment: This does work but I still want to know why the other one did not.  If no one else has any other suggestions after a while, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I build up a quick example in my current project and the css.erb file was compiled as one would expect. You can try to narrow it down: Fire up a new rails app using "rails new testapp" and see if your css.erb file is interpreted correctly. If it is, it is a problem with your current app and you can start comparing the configs.

Comment: 2.5 years later this was the most helpful answer to me. Including individual css.erb files (which I'm doing) is a pain, and this gets around that entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @TrevorMcKendrick, good to know this is still helpful :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found that my css files wouldn't be processed by ERB unless SCSS processing was also added.

I changed my `screen.css.erb` to `screen.css.scss.erb` and now `<%= asset_path 'file.png' %>` is rendered correctly as `/assets/file.png`.

I'm on Rails 3.1.3.

Comment: this is the solution that works... up past Rails +4.X

Comment: Spent 30 minutes banging my head against the wall until read your answer. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, I found that changing `asset_path` to `asset_data_uri` and then back to `asset_path` worked for me. Was using Rails 3.1.3 all along.

Strange.

Comment: Could it be because you updated the timestamp on all these files? If you renamed them all from .css to .css.erb but didn't alter the contents of the files, maybe rails didn't reload them in development.

Answer (score 0):

Sam Oliver's advice did the trick for me, simply renaming the extensions didn't update the timestamp on the files.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS and ERB**

The asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB. This means that if you add an erb extension to a CSS asset (for example, application.css.erb), then helpers like asset_path are available in your CSS rules:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

This writes the path to the particular asset being referenced. In this example, it would make sense to have an image in one of the asset load paths, such as app/assets/images/image.png, which would be referenced here. If this image is already available in public/assets as a fingerprinted file, then that path is referenced.

If you want to use a data URI — a method of embedding the image data directly into the CSS file — you can use the asset_data_uri helper.

**CSS and Sass:**

When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

```
image-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
image-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png".
```

The more generic form can also be used but the asset path and class must both be specified:

```
asset-url("rails.png", image) becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
asset-path("rails.png", image) becomes "/assets/rails.png"
```

Referenced By: [Rails Guide Asset Pipe Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Heading: 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 respectively.