# ERB not being imported by the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have recently upgraded an old app to Ruby on Rails 3.2.9. While enabling the asset pipeline, I changed my `css.scss` files to `css.scss.erb` so that I could use the helpers to load only the fingerprinted image files, like this:

```
`background: url(<%= asset_path "wishlist.png" %>)`
```

This works on standalone files, but when the `css.scss.erb` file has to be imported by `screen.css.scss`, it returns the following error:

```
`Invalid CSS after "...d: url(": expected ")", was "<%= asset_path ..."
```

I tried all the suggestions presented on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230725/css-in-rails-asset-path-not-processed-by-erb-in-development), but none of them avoids the error while making the app load the fingerprinted files.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the sass-helpers provided on the [Ruby on Rails Guide to the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) were using an hyphen instead of an underscore. Change everything to `image_path` instead of `image-path` (and so on) and it should work fine, like on this:

`background: url(image_path("wishlist.png"));`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct solution but if you are using sass-rails then you could use asset-path helper provided by it, like described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

Comment: I have tried that and, even though the app doesn't break, the images it uses are not the fingerprinted ones.

Just in case you notice I'm doing something wrong, I'm implementing it this way:
`background: url(asset-path("wishlist.png", image))`
or
`background: url(image-path("wishlist.png"))`

Comment: It works only in production, have you tested it in that mode?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the app does not break and `rake assets:precompile` runs correctly, but it still uses the non-fingerprinted version of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this link a shot:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Also you should check if your gems are updated.
Try adding "load 'deploy/assets'" to your Capfile (without the quotes)

If none of the above works, try turning off the debug on your develop env:
config.assets.debug = false (do that on your environments/development.rb)

That way you could try to inspect the code more freely without the need of deploying

Hope any of this helps. Share the results when the issues is solved! ;)

Comment: Another thing you could try is stop using Sprockets for css. Use it only for JS. You could use SASS @import statement instead of "require"